# Unusual gaps between divs, and anchor tag bug

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

I am attempting to attach a div on the bottom on my image with no spaces. However, the following code does not do what I ask of it. In addition to this, when hovering anywhere along the width of my `div h2`, the click button occurs, to indicate it is clickable in this blank space. I feel I have attempted everything to attach the black div and the image together, and make them both clickable without glitching or bugging with only one anchor tag. If you can help me, I would be extremely greatful.

Here is my current HTML code:

```
<div style="#">
    <a style="max-width: 280px;" href="#">
        <img src="../Images/7.JPG" style="height: 200px; width: 280px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;">          
        <div style="background-color: black; width: 280px; height: 30px; border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;">
            <h2 style="color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px;">Bees</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule, it is caused by initial margin of h2

```
<div style="max-width: 280px; overflow:hidden;" style="#">
    <a style="max-width: 280px;" href="#">
        <img src="../Images/7.JPG" style="height: 200px; width: 280px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; display: block;">          
        <div style="background-color: black; width: 280px; height: 30px; border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;">
            <h2 style="color: white; margin:0px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px;">Bees</h2>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crnbcqqL/2/) for you

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this didn't change anything.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a fiddle for you, check out the link

Comment: The gap has shrunk but is still existent. And the button is still clickable along the whole width of  `div h2`

Comment: You have wrapped the whole markup within anchor (a) tag, that's why it is clickable

Comment: I want it to be clickable, but only where the image and div is, not off to the side

Comment: Okay, i have updated the answer and fiddle as well, check it out

Comment: Thanks so much @Talha Abrar

Comment: Glad to help, please accept the answer so that others can take advantage as well

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here.

Your `<h2>` is overflowing trough the parent because of collapsible margins. Set the margin to 0 to fix it.

Either the `<a>` or the main `<div>` needs `display:inline-block` to not go 100% width.

Finally, don't use inline styles. Use `<style>` tag or style.css and add some classes and IDs.

```css
a{
  max-width: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
}

h2{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin: 0;
}

a div{
  background-color: black;
  width: 280px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/280/200/any">
      <div>
        <h2>Bees</h2>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```